# I tried making a class which checks if the number of arguments of a function is valid, but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, function, templates

Here is code I made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
template <class T, T(*func)(T ...)> class Foo {
public:
    template <class ...Args> Foo(const Args &...args) {
        func(static_cast<T>(args)...);
    }
};
int main() {
    Foo<int, &std::max>(0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

... So that Foo::Foo would throw error if the number of arguments is invalid.
But I get this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:23: error: could not convert template argument '& std::max' to 'int (*)(int, ...)
Foo<int, &std::max>(0, 1);
                  ^
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re trying to do.  The compiler already checks whether the number of arguments to a function is valid.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I think this "story" I made is enough to clarify it:https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-proposals/4vGE_j59GII

Comment: [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) is a function template, so you cannot just convert it to a pointer to function, you need an actual instantiation, like `std::max<int>`. Your code will still fail to compile because the signature of `std::max<int>` is not `int(int, ...)`

Comment: I still don’t understand what you’re trying to do.  Sorry.

Comment: @Praetorian I still got this error when I changed '&std::max' to '&std::max<int>'.

Comment: @Lorehead The point here is, I need a bind, which stores arguments, whose the number is same as the number of function's arguments.

Comment: @DannyuNDos I already said that alone won't fix your code. Look at the signature of `std::max`, it takes and returns `T const&`. `Foo` expects a different function signature, one which even has a variadic argument list. It is not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Like this? https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-proxies

Answer (score 0):

I workarounded something. Don't really know if it's useful to you, but here we go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
template <class T> class Foo {
public:
    template <class ...Args>
    const T& foo(const T & (*func)(const Args& ...), const Args &...args) {
        return func(static_cast<T>(args)...);
    }
};
int main() {
    std::cout << Foo<int>().foo(&std::max<int>, 0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

It actually fails compilation when you do something like:

```
Foo<int>().foo(&std::max<int>, 0, 1, 3);
```

### More generic and better (imho) solution(s)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
struct Foo {
    template <class ...Args>
    void check(T (func)(Args ...), Args&& ...args) {}
};

// maybe clearer
template<class T, class... Args>
void signatureChecker( T (func)(Args ...), Args&& ...args ) {}

void foo( int i, int x ) {}

int main() {

    int t = 3;
    const int& tt = t;

    // non const version accepts a initializer list
    Foo<int>().check( &std::max<int>, {3,3} );
    Foo<int>().check( &std::max<int>, {tt,3} );
    Foo<const int&>().check( &std::max<int>, tt, tt );
    Foo<void>().check( &foo, 2, 2 );

    signatureChecker<const int&>( &std::max<int>, tt, tt ); 
    signatureChecker<int>( &std::max<int>, {3,3} );

    return 0;
}
```

### Another solution using types directly instead of parameters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <class RetType, class... Args>
struct CheckSignature {
    template<RetType(func)(Args...)>
    struct ForFunction {};
};

int main() {
    CheckSignature<const int&, const int&, const int&>
        ::ForFunction<&std::max>();
    return 0;
}
```

With all these examples and modifications of what you're trying to achieve, I think you can suit them to your needs.